# Use Pagination With sortBy in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm trying to pull a few rows with a model in Laravel using pagination and sortBy.

Here is my Controller (without sorting):

```
    public function all(){
       $results['rows'] = Items::where('XXXX','YYYY')->paginate(32);
       return view('page', $results);
    }
```

This works fine. When I add sorting to it:

```
public function all(){
       $results['rows'] = Items::where('XXXX','YYYY')->paginate(32)->sortBy('TTT');
       return view('page', $results);
    }
```

The pagination on the blade template crashes. This is my code in blade:

```
<?php echo $rows->render(); ?>
```

I read a few questions here with a similar question, though the code didn't seem to be like mine and couldn't figure out how to implement it on my code. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `$rows->render();` ? It's wrong. change `$results['rows']` to `$rows` in your controller

Comment: But I have several other bits of information and I loop through them using the array key. $results['rows'], $results['images'] etc. This works perfectly. Only adding the sortBy kills it

Comment: I think your order is incorrect....   $results['rows'] = Items::where('XXXX','YYYY')->sortBy('TTT')->paginate(32);

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is the error I get when doing that:
BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 1999:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::sortBy()

Comment: Is there a way to sort $results['rows'] after I get the results?

Comment: @Avi why do you want to sort AFTER it gets fetched ? `sortBy()` is a collection method, wouldn't it be better to sort at db level using eloquent method `orderBy()`. `$results['rows'] = Items::where('XXXX','YYYY')->orderBy('TTT')->paginate(32);`

Comment: @Viney That's what I wanted in the first place but I get this error:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::sortBy()
Switching the sortBy() to the end of the call (after paginate() ) works but something in the pagination links breaks.

Comment: As Viney said, you should use `orderBy()` instead of `sortBy()`.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir and viney I just realized you wrote that orderBy is a better method (And I just figured that out before reading this) this absolutely works. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Avi Exactly! once you call `paginate()` on your result it's no more a simple collection rather it's an object of class `LengthAwarePaginator` so sorting here may sort the underlying Items collection but not their corresponding links. I've never done like this but I think might be the reason for messed up links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Viney said, use `orderBy()` instead of `sortBy()`:

```
$results['rows'] = Items::where('XXXX','YYYY')->orderBy('TTT')->paginate(32);
```